# Binding inside inputText inside dynaFormControl get null in primefaces

Tags: binding, primefaces-extensions

I try to bind component inside `dynaFormControl` but there is an error.

The code :

```
<pe:dynaForm id="dynaForm" value="#{dynaFormController.model}" var="data">
      <pe:dynaFormControl type="input" for="txt"  >
         <p:inputText id="txt" value="#{data.value}" binding="#{data.in}" />
      </pe:dynaFormControl>
</pe:dynaForm>
```

`in` is an `InputText` object, and when I run it, the page give this error :

> /dynamic.xhtml @18,81 binding="#{data.in}": Target Unreachable,
>   identifier 'data' resolved to null